# How to create a dynamodb table using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am trying below command after aws

```
--configure command:

aws dynamodb create-table 
--table-name MusicCollection2 
--attribute-definitions

 AttributeName=Artist,AttributeType=S AttributeName=SongTitle,AttributeType=S --

key-schema AttributeName=Artist,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=SongTitle,KeyType=RANGE 

--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5
```

> Output: Nothing

Please give suggestion how to create dyanmodb table using AWS CLI.

Comment: In addition to @notionquest's answer, here is a link on the [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Create the JSON file `create-table-movies.json` with the below content

   ```
   {
       "TableName": "MusicCollection2",
       "KeySchema": [
         { "AttributeName": "Artist", "KeyType": "HASH" },
         { "AttributeName": "SongTitle", "KeyType": "RANGE" }
       ],
       "AttributeDefinitions": [
         { "AttributeName": "Artist", "AttributeType": "S" },
         { "AttributeName": "SongTitle", "AttributeType": "S" }
       ],
       "ProvisionedThroughput": {
         "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
         "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
       }
   }
   ```
2. Browse to the file path on DOS command prompt (assuming Windows OS) and execute the below command

**Creates the table on local DynamoDB:-**

```
    aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://create-table-movies.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**To create the table on AWS DynamoDB service, please provide the correct region name. If your config is done already, it should work.**

```
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://create-table-movies.json --region us-west-2
```

**AWS CLI Configure:-**

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: accesskey
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: secretkey
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]:
```

Once you execute the above command, it updates the data on your profile (on windows).

```
C:\Users\<username>\.aws\
```

**Check the following files:-**

```
config   - should have the region name
credentials  - should have access key and secret key
```

**Credentials Sample:-**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = aaaadffewe
aws_secret_access_key = t45435egfdg456retgfg
```

**Config File Sample:-**

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: I am getting below error: CreateTable operation: 'Access' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) , what i am missing?

Comment: Updated answer with all the required details. If you have the details as I mentioned in my answer and still you get some error, then the problem could be on your access keys.

Comment: thanks @notionquest can you please give me idea to create more than one table using one json file.

Comment: Will check the feasibility. Has your original problem resolved? If yes, please accept the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a way to create 2 tables using one JSON file (i.e. command is not accepting the array of create table requests)

Comment: Thanks i was also thinking same.

Comment: Thank you! i was trying to find --cli-input-json on the documentation as it didn't make any sense not to exist as a feature but didn't see it

Answer (score 1):

aws dynamodb create-table --table-name contact --attribute-definitions AttributeName=name,AttributeType=S AttributeName=email,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=name,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=email,KeyType=RANGE --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1

Use this command instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).